# Accepting an array of JSON objects from a web service

Tags: java, android, json

I have set up a RESTful web service that includes the following:

```
    @GET
@Path("{from}/{to}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Story> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
    return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
}
```

which returns a list of all the Story objects in my database. I also have this:

```
    @GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Story find(@PathParam("id") Short id) {
    return super.find(id);
}
```

which returns a single Story object when I add "/{id}" to the end of the path. These both work fine on the server, and return expected results. On the client side, the latter method works perfectly using the following code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        String resprint = new String();

        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            // Get the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                // get entity contents and convert it to string
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
                resprint = result;
                // construct a JSON object with result
                object=new JSONObject(result);
                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {System.out.println("CPE"); e.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("IOE"); e.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (JSONException e) { System.out.println("JSONe"); e.printStackTrace();}

        System.out.println("FUCKYEAHBG: " + resprint);
        return object;
    }
```

}

My problem is that, when I try to use this same code with the first method, which should return a list of JSON Story objects, I get a JSON exception: Type Mismatch.

How can I change this code to accept an array of json objects rather than a single one?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out while I was asking the question: A JSONArray is a distinct type of object, independent of JSONObject, and thus the result of the get request must be declared as such:

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response;
        JSONArray object = new JSONArray();
        String resprint = new String();

        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            // Get the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                // get entity contents and convert it to string
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
                resprint = result;
                // construct a JSON object with result
                object=new JSONArray(result);
                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }
```

Figured I'd finish posting the question in case any other JSON noobs have this question.